Simulation of Ball balaner mechanism
I am trying to simulate a mechanism similar to a ball balancer similar to the image below (I got this image online) 
The Kinematic representation of the system would be something like:

(Links 1, 2 and 3 are controlled with motors)
I am unable to simulate this using ROS as URDF is not allowing me to connect all the three connectors to the same final link. Also the angle of the connector would change based on the position of all 3 links. I would like to visualise this on RVIZ and I am later trying to simulate this on Gazebo and CoppeliaSim.
How do I achieve this simulation. What method should I use?
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

why is the diagram upside down?

A URDF can't represent a closed kinematic chain, so you can't do this exactly how you want, but you can fake it by defining your three actuators as not connected to anything and then define a fourth actuator that doesn't have a visible linkage that attaches to the center of the plate. The fourth/virtual actuator will be constrained by the poses of the three real actuators by way of the plane fit on the three end effector positions.
